# Is it possible to test multiple apps with espresso test recorder?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

Is it possible to record tests for multiple apps with espresso test recorder or do you need to write code manually for these tests with UiAutomator?

Answer (score 2):

For background, see:

- Google's doc on [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html),
- Google's doc on [Espresso Test Reorder](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/espresso-test-recorder.html),
- Google's doc on [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html), and
- Alex Zhukovich's tutorial [Android testing: Espresso & UIAutomator together](http://alexzh.com/tutorials/android-testing-espresso-uiautomator-together/) about combining Espresso + UIAutomator to test multiple apps. (Also [Alex's previous tutorials](http://alexzh.com/tag/testing/) on Android unit testing, Mockito & Roboelectric, Espresso, and UIAutomator.)

The pair of tools should work to test an app's notifications, for instance.

But these docs don't discuss using the Espresso Test Recorder for multiple apps. The test recorder is in beta and still developing.

**Suggestion:** Try using Espresso Test Recorder to record actions and assertions within each app separately, then manually combine the two generated test programs.

Please report back on lessons learned!

Answer (score 0):

`Espresso` uses current applications context, so it means that you cannot do things like checking sharingIntent, notifications or opening another app.

You can make tests for each of your aplications, then write bash/python script for running them together, but as you think you cannot test multiple apps using single record or 'manual' test case.

I think that `UiAtomator` can make a thing as this a pure instrumentation testing framework, but I haven't used that yet.

Hope it will help.